# easy java swing arrayList.size() error? constructor parameter override? arrayList.size() not working? java

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, constructor

So I have searched the internet, javaDocs, and stack overflow vigorously but it seems my issue is too ambiguous. Clearly I'm missing something simple but I just don't see it.

This program is supposed to display a simple gui with a box with questions and the corresponding answers underneath. I haven't completed coding because I ran into this issue...

I set the one of the QuizCard constructors to clear both arrayList and then add a value to position 0. Those added values are the default questions displayed in the text area. I made methods that enable me to pass new questions into the program from the QuizCardTestDrive class bu for some reason the values won't pass. that and the arrayList.size() method doesn't return the proper value of the list. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class QuizCard implements Serializable{

private ArrayList<String> mQuestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> mAnswerList = new ArrayList<String>();

public QuizCard(String question, String answer) {
    mQuestionList.add(question);
    mAnswerList.add(answer);

}

public QuizCard() {
    mQuestionList.clear();
    mQuestionList.clear();

    mQuestionList.add(0, "What class is used for writing to a text file?");
    mAnswerList.add(0,"class FileWriter");
    }

public void setLists(String q, String a) {
    mQuestionList.add(q);
    mAnswerList.add(a);
}

public String getQuestion(int q) {

    if ((q > mQuestionList.size()) ) {
        q = 0;
    } 

    return mQuestionList.get(q);
}


public String getAnswer(int a)  {

    if ((a > mAnswerList.size()) ) {
         a = 0;
    } 
        return mAnswerList.get(a);
}

public int getQuestionListSize() {
    return mQuestionList.size();
}

public int getAnswerListSize() {
    return mAnswerList.size();
}

}

public class QuizCardTestDrive  extends QuizCard{

public static void main(String [] args) {       
    QuizCard b5 = new QuizCard();
    QuizCardBuilder qb = new QuizCardBuilder();

    System.out.println("The Answer List Size = " + b5.getAnswerListSize());
    System.out.println("The Question List Size = " + 
    b5.getQuestionListSize());

    b5.setLists("is This a test?", "DUHH!!!");
    b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");
    b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");
    b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");

    System.out.println("The Answer List Size = " + b5.getAnswerListSize());
    System.out.println("The Question List Size = " + 
    b5.getQuestionListSize());

    qb.setupGui();

}
}
public class QuizCardBuilder implements Serializable, ActionListener{
QuizCard qz = new QuizCard();

 int list;
JFrame frame;
JPanel background;

JTextArea areaN;
JTextArea areaS;
JButton buttonNext;
JLabel labelN;
JLabel labelS;
JScrollPane scrollN;
JScrollPane scrollS;

public void setupGui() {

    frame = new JFrame("Gray Garrett LLC Presents: QUIZ CARD FLASH 1.0");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    background = new JPanel();
    background.setBackground(Color.magenta);
    background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(background, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    areaN = new JTextArea(10,20);
    areaS = new JTextArea(10,20);

    areaN.setText(qz.getQuestion(0));
    areaS.setText(qz.getAnswer(0));

    areaN.setLineWrap(true);
    areaS.setLineWrap(true);

    scrollN = new JScrollPane(areaN);
    scrollN.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollN.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollS = new JScrollPane(areaS);
    scrollS.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollS.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    labelN = new JLabel("QUESTION");
    labelS = new JLabel("ANSWER");

    buttonNext = new JButton("NEXT");
    buttonNext.addActionListener(this);     

    background.add(labelN);
    background.add(scrollN);
    background.add(labelS);
    background.add(scrollS);
    background.add(buttonNext);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, background);

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    areaN.setText("");
    areaS.setText("");
    list++;

    if (list  > qz.getQuestionListSize()) {
        list = 0;   
    }

    //areaN.setText("");
    areaN.setText(qz.getQuestion(list));
}

class AnswerListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        for (int z = 0; z < qz.getQuestionListSize(); z++) {
        if (!areaN.equals(qz.getQuestion(z))) {
        areaS.setText(" ");
        areaS.setText("CUSTOM QUESTION HAS NOT BEEN SAVED!");
        }
        }

        areaS.setText("");
        areaS.setText(qz.getAnswer(list));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure you meant to do `mQuestionList.clear();
    mQuestionList.clear();` ?, I very much doubt. maybe `mQuestionList.clear(); mAnswerList.clear();`?

Comment: I though maybe everytime the constructor is called it would continuously add the same question and answer to the list so i used clear() to prevent  this. I tried running the code even without clear() and i get the same questions displayed repeated when i press the next button

Comment: what @Aominè meant is: "if you use `mQuestionList.clear()` once, you do not have to do it again in the very next statement"

Comment: oops, yea one was supposed to be mAnswerList.clear(); and mQuestionList.clear();

Comment: I changed it but that doesnt affect the run on the program...

Comment: Adding **swing** tag will get more attention to your question. Just saying...

Comment: What is the exact behavior you expected from running this program, what actually happened, and what is the part that you don't understand about it? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: supposed to display a question and answer on the frame (box layout, ascending order). clicking the next button should display the next question in the arrayList in the text areaN (and the corresponding question in areaS)
The default questions are what the constructors set.
The problem is that when running the program from QuizCardTestDrive the arrayLists.size() return a value of only 6, but the next button only shows 1 question!
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I added the swing tag to the post too,  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have five answers and questions at the very first time when executing your swing application in the main method.
You can also see the output first and the last on your console as follows

```
The Answer List Size = 1
The Question List Size = 1
The Answer List Size = 5
The Question List Size = 5
```

I think you have to pass the QuizCard object reference to QuizCardBuilder class which has 4 items already.

So, I changed the setupGui method with one QuizCard object as a argument.

I think you don't need to clear and identify the index of the list.
Checking the index arrange also don't be needed because you already have a list as a boundary-check constant in your QuizCardBuilder class.

You can have another whatever button that should verify the user's question corresponding with AnswerListener class which is not used anywhere.

You can see the differences between your code and mine.

It's not a good code but hope this helps you.

Here is full modification code named QuizCardTestDrive class:

```
package justtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class QuizCardTestDrive /*extends QuizCard*/ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuizCardBuilder qb = new QuizCardBuilder();

        QuizCard b5 = new QuizCard();
        System.out.println("The Answer List Size = " + b5.getAnswerListSize());
        System.out.println("The Question List Size = " + b5.getQuestionListSize());

        b5.setLists("is This a test?", "DUHH!!!");
        b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");
        b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");
        b5.setLists("adfadfad", "DUHH!!!");

        System.out.println("The Answer List Size = " + b5.getAnswerListSize());
        System.out.println("The Question List Size = " + b5.getQuestionListSize());

        qb.setupGui(b5);

    }
}



class QuizCard implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<String> mQuestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mAnswerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //public QuizCard(String question, String answer) {
    //  mQuestionList.add(question);
    //  mAnswerList.add(answer);

    //}

    final static String firstQuestion = "What class is used for writing to a text file?";
    final static String firstAnswer = "class FileWriter";

    public QuizCard() {
        //mQuestionList.clear();
        //mQuestionList.clear();
        //mQuestionList.add(0, "What class is used for writing to a text file?");
        //mAnswerList.add(0,"class FileWriter");

        mQuestionList.add(firstQuestion);
        mAnswerList.add(firstAnswer);

    }

    public void clearAnswers()
    {
        mAnswerList.clear();
    }

    public void clearQuestions()
    {
        mQuestionList.clear();
    }

    public void setLists(String q, String a) {
        mQuestionList.add(q);
        mAnswerList.add(a);

    }

    public String getQuestion(int q) {

        //if ((q > mQuestionList.size())) {
        //  q = 0;
        //}

        //return mQuestionList.get(q);
        return mQuestionList.get(q);
    }

    public String getAnswer(int a) 
    {
        //if ((a > mAnswerList.size())) {
        //  a = 0;
        //}
        //return mAnswerList.get(a);

        return mAnswerList.get(a);
    }

    public int getQuestionListSize() {
        return mQuestionList.size();
    }

    public int getAnswerListSize() {
        return mAnswerList.size();
    }

}

class QuizCardBuilder implements Serializable, ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //QuizCard b5 = new QuizCard();
    QuizCard qz;

    int list;
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel background;

    JTextArea areaN;
    JTextArea areaS;
    JButton buttonNext;
    JLabel labelN;
    JLabel labelS;
    JScrollPane scrollN;
    JScrollPane scrollS;

    public void setupGui(QuizCard qz) {
        this.qz = qz;
        frame = new JFrame("Gray Garrett LLC Presents: QUIZ CARD FLASH 1.0");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        background = new JPanel();
        background.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(background, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        areaN = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        areaS = new JTextArea(10, 20);

        areaN.setText(qz.getQuestion(0));
        areaS.setText(qz.getAnswer(0));

        areaN.setLineWrap(true);
        areaS.setLineWrap(true);

        scrollN = new JScrollPane(areaN);
        scrollN.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollN.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollS = new JScrollPane(areaS);
        scrollS.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollS.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        labelN = new JLabel("QUESTION");
        labelS = new JLabel("ANSWER");

        buttonNext = new JButton("NEXT");
        buttonNext.addActionListener(this);

        background.add(labelN);
        background.add(scrollN);
        background.add(labelS);
        background.add(scrollS);
        background.add(buttonNext);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, background);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        areaN.setText("");
        areaS.setText("");

        list++;

        if (list >= qz.getQuestionListSize()) {
            list = 0;
        }

        // areaN.setText("");
        areaN.setText(qz.getQuestion(list));
        areaS.setText(qz.getAnswer(list));
    }

    class AnswerListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            for (int z = 0; z < qz.getQuestionListSize(); z++) {
                if (!areaN.equals(qz.getQuestion(z))) {
                    areaS.setText(" ");
                    areaS.setText("CUSTOM QUESTION HAS NOT BEEN SAVED!");
                }
            }

            areaS.setText("");
            areaS.setText(qz.getAnswer(list));

        }
    }
}
```